# RStudio blogdown: Adding [permalinks] to config.toml in Academic theme appears to stop rendering

Tags: r, rendering, permalinks, hugo, blogdown

I have been attempting to set up a personal website using RStudio, the [blogdown](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown) package, the [Academic](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic) theme and the blogdown "Serve Site" RStudio addin.

I know next to nothing about all this and have been following the instructions in Alison Presmanes Hill's [blog](https://alison.rbind.io/post/up-and-running-with-blogdown/) and the [blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) book.

Everything was going well, i.e. when I made and saved changes to the text of contents, the serve site addin would detect the change and locally re-render the site. (This is all local to my development PC. I haven't attempted to deploy via Netlify yet.)

Then I tried to enable permalinks for posts, as [suggested in the blogdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html#options). This was done by adding the following text somewhere near the top of `config.toml`.

```
[permalinks]
    post = "/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"
```

After adding those lines the site would not re-render. That is, if I changed any text in the content files the rendered output did not pick up the changes. There were no error messages in the RStudio console.

I filed this on what appeared to be a [related issue in hugo-academic](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/534), but the owner was unable to replicate this as a purely hugo/academic issue.

> @rgayler I have set [permalinks] for all 4 types of content in a test
>   environment with the example site, running latest versions of Hugo and
>   Academic and cannot reproduce the issue which you have described.
>   Hence, based on the details which you have provided, it may possibly
>   be a bug relating to Blogdown/Rstudio.

In another reply to someone else about permalink problems from blogdown the hugo-academic owner also suggested that this (other, possibly related) problem was only arising for blogdown users - so was possibly a blogdown issue.

> @jananiravi it appears that this issue is only affecting
>   Blogdown/RStudio users and may be related to Blogdown/RStudio
>   compatibility with Hugo's permalinks and GetPage functionality.

I have created a minimal example. Unfortunately, it's two snapshots (commits) of an [entire website as generated by blogdown](https://github.com/rgayler/blogdown_reprex/commits/master). The 6th commit (SHA = cc0f2cb) shows the website while it is working. It corresponds to the Academic example installed following the [instructions](https://alison.rbind.io/post/up-and-running-with-blogdown/). The 7th commit (SHA = 2b0eefa) shows the website after adding and saving the permalink lines to `config.toml`, then changing and saving the header text of `about.md`. This change does not get rendered.

Any clues as to what is happening here would be greatly appreciated. For the moment I am working around this by doing without permalinks.

FWIW I am using:

- Hugo V 0.40.3
- Academic V 2.2.0
- RStudio V 1.1.447

  > devtools::session_info()
  >   Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >    setting  value
  >    version  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
  >    system   x86_64, linux-gnu
  >    ui       RStudio (1.1.447)
  >    language en_AU:en
  >    collate  en_AU.UTF-8
  >    tz       Australia/Melbourne
  >    date     2018-05-14

  Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   package   * version date       source
   backports   1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   base      * 3.4.4   2018-04-21 local
   blogdown    0.6     2018-04-18 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
   bookdown    0.7     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   compiler    3.4.4   2018-04-21 local
   datasets  * 3.4.4   2018-04-21 local
   devtools    1.13.5  2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   digest      0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   evaluate    0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
   graphics  * 3.4.4   2018-04-21 local
   grDevices * 3.4.4   2018-04-21 local
   htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
   knitr       1.20    2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   magrittr    1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
   memoise     1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
   methods   * 3.4.4   2018-04-21 local
   Rcpp        0.12.16 2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   rmarkdown   1.9     2018-03-01 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   rprojroot   1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   stats     * 3.4.4   2018-04-21 local
   stringi     1.2.2   2018-05-02 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
   stringr     1.3.1   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
   tools       3.4.4   2018-04-21 local
   utils     * 3.4.4   2018-04-21 local
   withr       2.1.2   2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   xfun        0.1     2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
   yaml        2.1.19  2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.4.4)

Answer (score 1):

There were three simultaneous problems:

1. RStudio V1.1 has a bug that prevented the error messages from the local web server being displayed in the console. Instructions for working around this issue are here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2248#issuecomment-387453849
2. There was a problem in the hugo-academic theme such that the presence of [broken links in a site would cause the site build to fail](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/runtime-error-invalid-memory-address-or-nil-pointer-dereference/11881). This is fixed by using a version of hugo-academic from after 2018-05-09.
3. I misunderstood how tables were parsed in TOML - a table runs until the next table or EOF. I inserted the permalinks table near the top of config .toml and before some arbitrary key/value pairs, which were consequently included in the permalinks table. This was fixed by moving the permalinks table to immediately before the first other table in config.toml